# Symfony2 & Doctrine: Optimizing Query (Fetching EAGER)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

Currently my query looks like this:

```
$customers = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('c')
                ->from('AppBundle:Customer', 'c')
                ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
                ->setFirstResult($offset)
                ->setMaxResults($max)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

This returns me all data of the Customer entity. However, in my Twig template I have to access the @ManyToMany relation that the Customer entity has with PhoneNumber. That causes an extra query. Now I am trying to optimize this query:

```
$customers = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('c')
                ->addSelect('ph')
                ->from('AppBundle:Customer', 'c')
                ->leftJoin('AppBundle:PhoneNumber', 'ph', 'WITH', 'ph MEMBER OF c.phoneNumbers')
                ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
                ->setFirstResult($offset)
                ->setMaxResults($max)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

**Problem**
Problem with this query is that it returns the PhoneNumbers all by itself. Meaning that in $customers I don't have Customers with PhoneNumbers. Instead $customers is an array of Customers and PhoneNumbers. Over such an array I can't iterate properly. How can i fix this problem?

**Dump Extract**

```
    object(stdClass)#2171 (12) {
      ["__CLASS__"]=>
      string(32) "Updoon\AppBundle\Entity\Customer"
      ["phoneNumbers"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(35) "Updoon\AppBundle\Entity\PhoneNumber"
        [1]=>
        string(35) "Updoon\AppBundle\Entity\PhoneNumber"
      }
      ["id"]=>
      int(34)
   }

   object(stdClass)#2171 (9) {
      ["__CLASS__"]=>
      string(35) "AppBundle\Entity\PhoneNumber"
      ["customers"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(32) "AppBundle\Entity\Customer"
      }
      ["id"]=>
      int(95)
      ["number"]=>
      string(11) "51 06 20 20"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost correct. I would change:

- remove an extra `addSelect()` - put everything in a single `select()`
- change the `leftJoin` to utilize `@ManyToMany` relation

So, something like this:

```
    $customers = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c', 'ph')
    ->from('AppBundle:Customer', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.phoneNumbers', 'ph')
    ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
    ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($max)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you, even more simple than I thought.

Comment: There is one problem though: This solution only returns 1 record of the ManyToMany relationship. Do you have an idea on how to return all records? Because currently I can only print one PhoneNumber in my template, however, I want to print all of them in a for-loop.

Comment: The query in my post selects everything but structures it wrong. Your query is structured correctly but it only returns one record per ManyToMany-Relation. I need all records of that relation.

Comment: Can you update the question with your entities? This should work, no matter the number of phone numbers. Also, try querying without `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`...

Comment: Oh, it seems to work. I have a similiar issue with a OneToMany relation now. I try to fetch Customers with ManyToMany PhoneNumbers and OneToMany Addresses. With OneToMany-relations your solution doesn't work. Do you have an idea why?